# Definition of negatives in NT-Xent loss

Tags: self-supervised-learning, contrastive-learning

I'm trying to understand few details about NT-Xent loss defined in SimCLR paper([link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.05709)). The loss is defined as

$$\mathcal{l}_{i,j} = -\log\frac{\exp(sim(z_i,z_j)/\tau)}{\sum_{k=1}^{2N}\mathbb{1}_{[k\neq i]} \exp(sim(z_i,z_k)/\tau)}$$

Where $z_i$ and $z_j$ represent two augmentations for the same image. What I don't understand is: at the denominator, I understand that we want to exclude the point $z_i$ using the indicator function but shouldn't we exclude also $z_j$? Otherwise we will have $k=j$ for some $k$. Essentially, why we do let the positive sample at the denominator?

Answer (score 3):

To train the model, you take $N$ samples then build $N$ pairs by means of applying two different augmentations. So the total num. of samples is $2N$. Now, you take one pair $(i,j)$ and consider that to be *positive*. The remaining $N-1$ pairs (so $2(N-1)=2N-2$ samples) are *negatives*.

For each positive pair $(i,j)$ you compute the similarity of the positive pair at the numerator, and normalize it by the sum of similarities between the anchor $i$ and the negative $k$: if you reason on pairs, instead of single samples, you have that $k\neq j$. Maybe in the paper is not so clear, but $i$ and $j$ are positive because they are two different views of the same input sample (say $x$), instead $(i, k)$ and $(k, j)$ are negatives because $k$ is a view from another input (say $x'$, where $x\neq x'$.) So, when computing the denominator you do *not* include $j$. I found a [blog post](https://theaisummer.com/simclr/) that explains that too.

Lastly, the loss is also computed on $(j,i)$ pairs, so you sum it and divide by 2 times the batch size $N$.

Comment: mmmh ok but to have normalized probabilities shouldn't I also include the index $i$ itself? Thanks for your answer, but could you elaborate a bit more please? I would like to have this point clear.

Comment: @JamesArten I've edited my answer, I hope is clearer now

Comment: `For the denominator we need both the positive and negative pairs.`
The blog post you cited explicitly says this, where did you read that you do _not_ include j in the denominator?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this part: $$\frac{\exp(sim(z_i,z_j)/\tau)}{\sum_{k=1}^{2N}\mathbb{1}_{[k\neq i]} \exp(sim(z_i,z_k)/\tau)}$$
you will notice that it's similar to:
$$\frac{\exp(x_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}\exp(x_j)}$$
Which is basically a softmax function.
It's essentially a way to normalize the loss function so that all the probabilities sum up to 1. In the SimCLR case, you only have to exclude k=i, because of course the similarity of a sample with itself will always be 1.

Essentially this normalization is the reason why the positive samples (similarity close to 1.0) are pushed away from negative samples (similarity close to 0).